# Jquery AJAX GET with an email and ASP.NET ApiController

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, http

I have an action that checks if a user exist based on the username or email:

```
[Route("check/{usernameOrEmail}")]
[ResponseType(typeof(bool))]
public IHttpActionResult GetUserExists(string usernameOrEmail)
{
    var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Name == usernameOrEmail) ??
        db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == usernameOrEmail);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return Ok(false);
    }
    return Ok(true);
}
```

The AJAX method I am currently using looks like this:

```
var url = "api/users/check/" + usernameOrEmail;
$.get(url, function (data) {
    ...//Do stuff
});
```

This works perfectly well with a simple username but when using an email such as "test@test.com" I get the error:

> POST https://localhost:44301/api/users/check/test@test.com 404 (Not Found)

I believe this is because of the `@` symbol within the URL. I know I could use `POST` instead of `GET` and put the `usernameOrEmail` within the body but I would like to respect the RESTful HTTP verbs.

Is there an easy way I could encode the `@` symbol (or any others) to be sent in the URL as well as be parsed by my `ApiController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to encode your URL, try [encodeURIComponent( )](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuricomponent.asp) javascript method.

**From the link:**

> This function encodes special characters. In addition, it encodes the
>   following characters: , / ? : @ & = + $ #

**Encode a URI:**

```
var uri = "http://w3schools.com/my test.asp?name=ståle&car=saab";
var res = encodeURIComponent(uri);
```

**The result of res will be:**

```
http%3A%2F%2Fw3schools.com%2Fmy%20test.asp%3Fname%3Dst%C3%A5le%26car%3Dsaab
```

You can use [this](http://www.url-encode-decode.com/) website to test your encoding and decoding.

```
@ encoded -> %40 (UTF-8)
```

The following is a server-side solution:

Try [HttpServerUtility.HtmlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) .net framework method.

Comment: OP needs to encode on the client not on the server.

Comment: `encodeURI` did not work but instead I used `var uri = "api/users/check/" + encodeURIComponent(usernameOrEmail)` which output "/api/users/check/test%40test.com" which also had a `404` Is it the period in `.com` that is screwing it up now?

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer a couple of minutes ago. The encode uri documentation: " This function encodes special characters, except: , / ? : @ & = + $ # (Use encodeURIComponent() to encode these characters)." @samueldavidson

Comment: Okay so do you have any idea why I am still getting a 404? The period confuses ASP.NET, trying `test%40testcom` works fine but as soon as I add a period or %2E I get a `404`. Maybe I should just make a new question for that specific question?

Comment: try adding constraints to your route. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269867/how-to-convert-query-string-parameters-to-route-in-asp-net-mvc-4

Comment: @SamuelDavidson No, the problem is that you don't have the full route in your attribute. you need to add it starting with api.

Comment: or take api/users off of your url.

Comment: I figured it out from googling around. Its just a bug with ASP.NET, appending a `/` to the end of the URL fixes the 404. So my URL is `localhost:44301/api/users/check/test%40test.com/`. Kind of dumb but its works!

Answer (score 0):

You have to encode the string in your JS.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent